# custom SCC to access hostPath throws permission denied on the pod

Tags: openshift

I use `openshift 4.7` and have this custom `SCC` (the goal is to have read-only access on some directories in the host node):

```
allowHostDirVolumePlugin: true
allowHostIPC: false
allowHostNetwork: false
allowHostPID: false
allowHostPorts: false
allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
allowPrivilegedContainer: false
apiVersion: security.openshift.io/v1
fsGroup:
  type: RunAsAny
groups:
- system:cluster-admins
kind: SecurityContextConstraints
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/description: 'test scc'
  name: test-access
priority: 15
readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
runAsUser:
  type: RunAsAny
seLinuxContext:
  type: RunAsAny
supplementalGroups:
  type: RunAsAny
volumes:
- 'hostPath'
- 'secret'
```

and here is my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-test
  namespace: ubuntu-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu-test
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ubuntu-test
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu-test
        image: ubuntu:latest
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
        args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 256Mi
        
        volumeMounts:
          - name: docker
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          - name: containers
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /var/log/containers
          - name: pods
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /var/log/pods
      volumes:
        - name: docker
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
            type: ''
        - name: containers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/containers
            type: ''
        - name: pods
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/pods
            type: ''
```

But when I `rsh` to the container, I can't see the mounted `hostPath`:

```
root@ubuntu-test-6b4fcb5bd7-fnc6f:/# ls /var/log/pods
ls: cannot open directory '/var/log/pods': Permission denied
```

As I check the permissions, everything seems fine:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 44 root root   8192 Oct 12 14:30 pods
```

Answer (score 0):

Using selinux can solve this problem. Reference article: https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/selinux-policy-for-openshift-containers-40baa1c86aa5

In addition: You can refer to the selinux parameters to set the addition, deletion, and modification of the mount directory https://selinuxproject.org/page /ObjectClassesPerms

Answer (score 0):

In openshift4, if you use hostpath as the backend data volume, you need to configure the selinux policy when selinux is enabled. By default, you need to give `container_file_t`